# STRIPE : This customer has no attached payment source or default payment method. RUBY ON RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I've got some issues, i'm trying to implement subscription with stripe > it works when there is for exemple 3 items in my order > it create a subscription for the 3 items.
The problem is that if the customer wants to stop sub only for ONE element, i dont know how to handle this ...

So i was wondering to create a subscription for each element, this is my code

```
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create
    @order.line_items.each do |line_item|
      product = Stripe::Product.create(
        {
          name: line_item.product.name,
          metadata: {
            product_id: line_item.product.id,
            line_item_id: line_item.id
          }
        }
      )

      price = Stripe::Price.create(
        {
          product: product.id,
          unit_amount: line_item.product.price_cents,
          currency: 'eur',
          recurring: {
            interval: 'month'
          }
        }
      )

      Stripe::Subscription.create({
        customer: customer.id,
        items: [
          {price: price.id, quantity: line_item.quantity}
        ]
      })
```

but i got this error **This customer has no attached payment source or default payment method.**
and i dont know how to attach it, even with documentation..

any help please ? thank you

Comment: Can you clarify what problem you're encountering? You started off talking about a subscription with multiple items and how to cancel a subset, but then ended with a payment method error on subscription creation, which is unrelated. For the payment error, you need to either provide a `default_payment_method` for the subscription or attach a payment method to the customer and set it as their default for invoices with `invoice_settings.default_payment_method`.

Comment: Ok so on my website you can rent some items > so i need subscription with stripe > i succeedeed if you rent 3 items in one order but it creates only one subscription, and if you want to keep only 2 items next month i dont know how to handle that .

So on my code you can see that i've tried to create a subscription for each item, so finally you can decide which one you want to keep or not individually .

I want to charge the customer one time for every item in his cart and after he can manage every subscription by himself.

Comment: Ok, so you want to know how to manage multiple subscriptions (or multiple items on a single subscription) then? If you've solved the problem with the payment method I suggest removing that for clarity.

Comment: i finally solved my probleme thank you !

Comment: @BenoîtBargès How did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As said in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63507984/8740349#comment112302062_63507984); To fix the error in the title:

- You need to first have the "payment method", if you haven't already, create one:

  - Maybe using Stripe.js and it's elements API.
  - Which nowadays has "payment" element, allowing users to choose their payment-method.
  - And supports Setup-Intent's "client_secret" (beside Payment-Intent's), submittable using `confirmSetup(...)` method.

Then (using Stripe API):

- Attach said "payment method" to the Customer:

  - (Optionally) set it as their default for invoices (with `invoice_settings.default_payment_method`).
- And, while creating the subscription, pass the `customer` (that which you atteched said "payment method" to).